# Pulling the name of a Word bookmark from an excel range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on something that users fill in on an excel sheet, press a button and it pushes the data to a bookmark in word.

The script works fine, but currently I can only pass data to a location named manually in in VBA code, whereas I want to be able to look up the name of the bookmark from a cell in excel. Basically = IF there's a value in B copy the text in C to the word doc bookmark named in A.

I'm not sure how to achieve this, code below for reference.

```
Sub pop()

Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim oDocRange As Word.Range
Dim oBkmRange As Word.Range

Set oWord = New Word.Application
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\doc.docx", ReadOnly:=False)
Set oDocRange = oDoc.Content
oWord.Visible = True


Dim i As Integer


If Not oDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Bookmark_1") Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set oBkmRange = oDocRange.Bookmarks("Bookmark_1").Range

For i = 2 To 20
    If Worksheets("Text").Range("B" + CStr(i)).Value = "Yes" Then
        Worksheets("Text").Range("D" + CStr(i)).Copy
        oBkmRange.Collapse 0  'WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        oBkmRange.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but I'll give it a go.

Let's put the bookmark name in cell A1. Then you pick it up like this:

```
BookmarkName = Worksheets("Text").Range("A1").Value
```

And then you use it in your references like this:

```
Set oBkmRange = oDocRange.Bookmarks(BookmarkName).Range
```

Comment: Hi Sam, that's what I've tried but I get Type Mismatch on the Set oBkRange

Comment: It might be a flaw in the logic. "If Not Exists" is follow by some code that relies on the bookmark to exist. Otherwise, I think your code is fine. I tried it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Place the setting of the bookmark object inside the loop and assign it to the cell in column of row *i*.

```
Option Explicit

Sub pop()

    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim oDocRange As Word.Range
    Dim oBkmRange As Word.Range

    Set oWord = New Word.Application
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\doc.docx", ReadOnly:=False)
    Set oDocRange = oDoc.Content
    oWord.Visible = True

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 20

        With Worksheets("Text")

            If .Range("B" + CStr(i)).Value = "Yes" Then

                Dim bookmarkName As String
                bookmarkName = .Range("A" + CStr(i)).Value

                If Not oDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName) Then

                    Set oBkmRange = oDocRange.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range

                    .Range("D" + CStr(i)).Copy

                    oBkmRange.Collapse 0
                    oBkmRange.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)

                End If

            End If

        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott, deleted my previous comment as I was looking at a different file. This seems like it would work, however it doesn't actually paste into the word document.

Comment: @chefman179 try `oBkmRange.Text = .Range("D" + Cstr(i)).Value` in place of 3 lines in inner most if block. Not sure 100% on syntax but idea is to write the text straight to the bookmark. If that syntax is off, please google setting text in word bookmark via vba. There's a ton of stuff out there on it.